# Add new row on the top of the grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

**i have a gridview thad adds new row to it at the end of the grid....code for doin so is**

```
protected void addRow(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int rowIndex = 0;

        if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
            DataRow drCurrentRow = null;
            if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    TextBox amount = (TextBox)Grid_AccEntry.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].FindControl("amount");
                    DropDownList DrCr = (DropDownList)Grid_AccEntry.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("DrCr");
                    DropDownList account = (DropDownList)Grid_AccEntry.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("account");
                    DropDownList oprUnit = (DropDownList)Grid_AccEntry.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("oprUnit");
                    DropDownList dept = (DropDownList)Grid_AccEntry.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("dept");
                    DropDownList affiliate = (DropDownList)Grid_AccEntry.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[5].FindControl("affiliate");
                    DropDownList openItem = (DropDownList)Grid_AccEntry.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[6].FindControl("openItem");
                    TextBox lineNar = (TextBox)Grid_AccEntry.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[7].FindControl("lineNar");

                    drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();

                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["amount"] = amount.Text.Trim() == "" ? 0 : Convert.ToDecimal(amount.Text);
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["DrCr"] = DrCr.Text;
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["account"] = account.Text;
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["oprUnit"] = oprUnit.Text;
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["dept"] = dept.Text;
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["affiliate"] = affiliate.Text;
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["openItem"] = openItem.Text;
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["lineNar"] = lineNar.Text;
                    rowIndex++;
                }

                dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
                ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dtCurrentTable;

                Grid_AccEntry.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
                Grid_AccEntry.DataBind();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("ViewState is null");
        }
        SetPreviousData();
    }




    private void SetPreviousData()
    {
        int rowIndex = 0;
        if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    TextBox amount = (TextBox)Grid_AccEntry.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].FindControl("amount");
                    DropDownList DrCr = (DropDownList)Grid_AccEntry.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("DrCr");
                    DropDownList account = (DropDownList)Grid_AccEntry.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("account");
                    DropDownList oprUnit = (DropDownList)Grid_AccEntry.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("oprUnit");
                    DropDownList dept = (DropDownList)Grid_AccEntry.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("dept");
                    DropDownList affiliate = (DropDownList)Grid_AccEntry.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[5].FindControl("affiliate");
                    DropDownList openItem = (DropDownList)Grid_AccEntry.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[6].FindControl("openItem");
                    TextBox lineNar = (TextBox)Grid_AccEntry.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[7].FindControl("lineNar");

                    amount.Text = dt.Rows[i]["amount"].ToString();
                    DrCr.Text = dt.Rows[i]["DrCr"].ToString();
                    account.Text = dt.Rows[i]["account"].ToString();
                    oprUnit.Text = dt.Rows[i]["oprUnit"].ToString();
                    dept.Text = dt.Rows[i]["dept"].ToString();
                    affiliate.Text = dt.Rows[i]["affiliate"].ToString();
                    openItem.Text = dt.Rows[i]["openItem"].ToString();
                    lineNar.Text = dt.Rows[i]["lineNar"].ToString();

                    //to bind long narr text to gridview line narr
                    TextBox lineNar1 = (TextBox)Grid_AccEntry.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[7].FindControl("lineNar");
                    if (lineNar1.Text == "")
                        lineNar1.Text = lngNar.Text;

                    rowIndex++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**this adds new row at the end of the grid....but i want to add new row at the top...what changes i have to do to this code???**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code adds new row at the end of the grid because you add new row at the last index of the DataTable. Instead of that you should at it at **0th index**. You can use **InsertAt** method for that as shown in below example :

```
var dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
var newRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();
dtCurrentTable.Rows.InsertAt(newRow, 0);
```

Comment: its my pleasure. have a nice day ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use Insert method to insert row at Top in Gridview just implement this method

> insert(index: number, item: any): void

example:

```
gridview1.Rows.Insert(0,item);
```

Comment: Exactly what I need, Thanks.